# python parse xml and get attributes values for each subelement under root

Tags: xml, python-2.7, parsing, lxml

I'm using xpath to search for attirbutes but I'm not sure how I can get attributes for each subelement under root

Here's my example xml file

```
<User>
  <Name>abcd</Name>
  <Groups>
     <GroupName>A</GroupName>
     <groupName>B</GroupName>
  </Groups>
</User>
<User>
  <Name>zxcv</Name>
  <Groups>
     <GroupName>A</GroupName>
     <GroupName>C</GroupName>
  </Groups>
</User>
```

I want to retrieve group names associated with each user by tag "Name"
Is this possible in python ?

When I use lxml xpath for GroupName, I just get a list of GroupNames like the following:

A

A

B

C

so there is no way to see which groups are associated which user

If I can somehow distinguish this, maybe I can build a dictionary with the key as the user and values as the groups, but I'm not sure how

This is my first post to stack overflow, I apologize if I missed something or did not provide all the needed information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! ProTip: It's helpful to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You were partially there; we just needed the code and desired output.

I think what you're trying to get are the text nodes of the `Name` and `GroupName` elements. You don't actually have any attributes in your XML. (Using the correct terminology will help you avoid a lot of confusion. Maybe take a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/)

What I would do is select each `User`, then use the `Name` to create an item in the dictionary that contains a list. Then you can select the `GroupName` elements and add those to the list for the current `User`.

Example...

```
from lxml import etree

# Added "doc" root element to make the XML well-formed.
xml = """
<doc>
    <User>
        <Name>abcd</Name>
        <Groups>
            <GroupName>A</GroupName>
            <GroupName>B</GroupName>
        </Groups>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Name>zxcv</Name>
        <Groups>
            <GroupName>A</GroupName>
            <GroupName>C</GroupName>
        </Groups>
    </User>
</doc>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

users = {}
for user in tree.xpath("//User"):
    name = user.xpath("Name")[0].text
    users[name] = []
    for group in user.xpath("Groups/GroupName"):
        users[name].append(group.text)

print users
```

this will output (print)...

```
{'abcd': ['A', 'B'], 'zxcv': ['A', 'C']}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great, i have also found another way but this is much simpler with lxml